Web-based RSS reader
Are there any web-based RSS readers that will parse a given RSS feed and display it in a nice UI?
There's a lot of websites that are inaccessible without javascript, but which do provide an RSS feed. I'm looking for a website that can serve as a quick alternative frontend for such websites.
For example, consider my mastodon feed
Website doesn't load without JavaScript

https://mastodon.social/@MichaelAltfield

RSS feed doesn't require JavaScript (but there's no UI)

https://mastodon.social/@MichaelAltfield.rss

Here's the requirements:

Free
Open-Source (ideally AGPL)
Nice UX
It "just works" in firefox and chromium (with no additional installation required)
I can include the RSS feed in the URL itself (eg view-rss.net/?feed=mastodon.social/@MichaelAltfield.rss)
Doesn't require me to create an account
Doesn't require JavaScript

Are there any websites that can parse & display a nice UI for a given RSS feed?

self hosted or 'service' ?

either would suffice
